# Eclipse Lisp Plug-in does not evaluate on mac

Tags: macos, mac, eclipse, plugins, lisp

Hi
I am using the Dandelion Eclipse Lisp Plug-in (http://sourceforge.net/projects/dandelion-ecl/) on Mac OSX. 

I have a windows PC and this plug-in is running ok on it. But when I am using it to evaluate my code on my mac, it prompted me:

"Starting eval server failed

Cannot run program 
"/Users/Allan/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/de.defmacro.dandelion.env.clisp.mac.ppc_2.4.9/binary/environment_clisp_2.4.9": error=13, Permission denied"

I tried to run eclipse by using sudo command, but the error was still there. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Setting execution permission should solve your problem:

```
chmod +x /Users/Allan/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/de.defmacro.dandelion.env.clisp.mac.ppc_2.4.9/binary/environment_clisp_2.4.9
```

Comment: when doing this should I see some sort of output? I run the chmod+ command with sudo and nothing happens

Comment: The `chmod` command does not produce any output. It just changes the execution status of the file. You can see the result if you do `ls -l the-file` once _before_ executing the `chmod` and once _after_ it.